# Problem with FindRoot output

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

Consider the following function:

$$ f(x)=\beta~e^{-x^2}-\frac{\beta +e}{e~x}+1~, $$

where $\beta$ is some parameter and $e$ represents the Euler constant.

I've been trying to get Mathematica to find the roots, using

```
FindRoot[1 + β E^-x^2 - (E + β)/(E x), {x, 1.4}]
```

However there seems to be some problem when, for instance, $\beta=2.3$, since `FindRoot` outputs $\text{x=1.32902}$ but the function is only zero, for that value of $\beta$, when $x=0$.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** The answers by David Keith and John Doty are absolutely correct. However it seems I have not formulated the question in the right way. My problem is not that with that code Mathematica cannot find the right answer (gets stuck in a local minimum) but the fact that it outputs an incorrect answer without showing some kind of error message. I'm using version 11.0.

Comment: Please add your code in copyable form (not as image) to your post so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Sorry for the inconvenience. Mathematica.SE was complaining about code formatting and the only way I got it to post the question was by removing all the code. I think now it works.

Comment: Sometimes, reformulating the the function helps. Multiplying `1 + β E^-x^2 - (E + β)/(E x)` by `x` introduces an artificial root at `0` but `FindRoot[E x (1 + E^-x^2 \[Beta]) == E + \[Beta], {x, 1.4}]` works nicely...

Comment: @MichaelE2 The point of the whole question was that I did(do) not receive the error message in Mathematica 11.0. In the edit paragraph is explained. I'll remove your edit

Comment: @PML Oh, sorry.  I don't have 11.0, but 10.4.3 and 11.2, 11.3 each give the error message.  Unless you've done something to your 11.0 (turned off the error message, changed the defaults for `FindRoot`, etc.), it looks like a bug that came and went. Maybe someone with 11.0 will come along and verify. (I still think it might be better to explicitly mention `FindRoot::lstol`, which should have been emitted.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, it's a very odd behaviour (because older versions throw the error message). My installation in pretty vanilla. The error messages are thrown for every other function that I use. Well serves me right: should keep the software up to date. Ty for your time, nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a better starting point. Your function has a minimum around 1.3, so `FindRoot` finds that and doesn't look farther.

```
FindRoot[1 + \[Beta] E^-x^2 - (E + \[Beta])/(E x), {x, 0.5}]
(* {x -> 1.} *)
```

In Mathematica 11.3, it reports a **FindRoot::lstol** message for an initial starting point of 1.4 before returning the `x` value for the minimum.

Comment: But it's not a root...For $\beta<2.3$ it has no problems going all the way to $x=1$

Comment: `x -> 1.` certainly is a root. `1 + \[Beta] E^-x^2 - (E + \[Beta])/(E x) /. x -> 1.` yields `-2.22045*10^-16`, zero within rounding error. For an initial guess of `1.4`, I get a **FindRoot::lstol** error message. `FindRoot` uses Newton's method, and is thus sensitive to your initial guess.

Comment: Of course $x=1$ is a root. What I meant is that for my starting point FindRoot gets stuck in a local minimum but that minimum is not a root

Comment: That's the nature of the method. It can get stuck.And it complains with an error message, as it should.

Comment: Oh I missed your point: it complains that it can't find a root in your case. In my case - with the code that I posted - it simply returns that output. No error message. I've checked the "messages board" and there's nothing there. What version are you using. I'm using 11.0

Comment: I'm using 11.3 on Mac.

Comment: So it seems I need to update. Thank you for you patience. I would like to accept you answer. Can you reformulate it by stating that in mathematica 11.3 an error message is thrown?

Answer (score 5):

The Newton method gets stuck at a local minimum. Try this:

```
In[1]:= exp = 1 + \[Beta] E^-x^2 - (E + \[Beta])/(E x);

In[2]:= sol = 
  FindRoot[exp /. \[Beta] -> 2.3, {x, .5, 2}, Method -> "Brent"];

In[3]:= exp /. \[Beta] -> 2.3 /. sol

Out[3]= 8.8773433*10^-13
```

Comment: Note that the default method also works here if given `{x, .5, 2}` as the initial guess.

Comment: Thanks, John. I did not try that. I used Brent’s method because it will maintain a bracket and not stall in a local min.

Comment: It appears that `FindRoot` defaults to Brent's method when given two starting points. Using `EvaluationMonitor` shows an identical trajectory.

Comment: That makes sense. Newton’s method really can’t make use of two starting points.

Answer (score 0):

ContourPlot shows two solution-branches and bifurcation:

```
pic=ContourPlot[0 == 1 + \[Beta] E^-x^2 - (E + \[Beta])/(E x), {\[Beta], 0, 5}, {x,0, 3}, FrameLabel -> {\[Beta], x}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Obviously the bifurcation might be the reason why FindRoot fails to find all solutions!

A very easy way to solve the equation is to solve for `\[Beta][x]` as a function of x (analytically)

```
erg\[Beta] =Solve[0 == 1 + \[Beta] E^-x^2 - (E + \[Beta])/(E x),\[Beta]][[1]]
(*{\[Beta] -> (E^(1 + x^2) (-1 + x))/(E^x^2 - E x)}*)

\[Beta]x = Table[{\[Beta], x} /. erg\[Beta], {x, 0.5, 3, .2}]
(* {{23.2332, 0.5}, {4.92134, 0.7}, {3.0776, 0.9}, {2.50863,1.1}, {2.34368,1.3}, {2.38344, 1.5}, {2.56035, 1.7}, {2.84377,1.9}, {3.21305, 2.1}, {3.64878, 2.3}, {4.13162, 2.5}, {4.64434,2.7}, {5.17382, 2.9}} *)

Show[{pic, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[\[Beta]x]}]}]
```

[image]

**answer**
The point`{\[Beta] = 2.338 , x = 1.349 }` is a solution, so FindRoot's answer is correct!

Comment: Of course your text is correct, but it is not an answer to my question. Correctly you say that for that value of $\beta$ there are two roots, but my point was, for smaller values of $\beta$ there is only one root, and yet FindRoot still outputted a result without throwing an error (being stuck in a minimum)

Comment: If I try, as you suggest in your question, `With[{\[Beta] = 2.3}, 
 FindRoot[1 + \[Beta] E^-x^2 - (E + \[Beta])/(E x), {x, 1.4}]]` FindRoot gives an error `FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.` I believe this is correct, because solutions x (beside x==1) only exist if `\[Beta]>2.33815`